# align a column in SharePoint list?

Tags: list, css

Is it possible to align columns in a SharePoint list? maybe using CSS?

[image]

The months are single lines of text.

The figures are currency.

this makes the months left aligned and the currency right aligned, not the easiest to read ( this is an example with small figures and 4 columns so it is not too bad to look at, my actual list has lots of entries, columns and 7 figure numbers making it laboursome to read)

Any pointers would be appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, CSS is the way to go. By default all currency and percentage columns align to the right. This blog post will give you what you need: http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2012/05/text-alignment-sharepoint-list/

Comment: This worked perfect thanks, had a bit of trouble with the headers so just aligned them using SPD